# Angular: struggling to Route back to a Certain part of the Web App

Tags: angular

I'm not sure where I am going wrong but I keep getting an error when using a Router Link to go to my Home page on closing a page via a button:

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img [src]="brandLogo" [alt]="brandAlt" class="brand-logo-style" tabindex="0"/>
    <h1 class="header-text">Thanks for registering your interest!</h1>
    <p class="main-text">
       Our marketing and research departments want to hear from you
       and may contact you via email for your thoughts and feedback to make Raiys even better.
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="main-text">
        Don’t worry you can opt out at any time in your profile.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="confirm-button" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="pam-primary-button"
            aria-label="confirm communication preferences"
            [routerLink]="close"
            >Close
    </button>
  </div></div>
```

TS:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { appRoutesNames } from 'src/app/app.routes.names';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thank-you-feedback',
  templateUrl: './thank-you-feedback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thank-you-feedback.component.scss']
})
export class ThankYouFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {

  brandLogo = '';
  brandAlt = '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

 close = `${appRoutesNames.LOGIN}`

}
```

All that seems to happen is it applies \login to the URL and gives me a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
close = `/${appRoutesNames.LOGIN}`
```

add / to the routes will work

Comment: Ah I see where it waswrong, thank you